# Select specific closest element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, closest

I have the following html :

```
  <table id="objects">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="delete">link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="4" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="delete">link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
```

When I click anchor tag I'd like to select `<input>` closest to my link, and get it's value. How can I do this ? I was trying :

```
  $('.delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).closest('input').attr('value');
    alert(val);
  });
```

but without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the `closest` function is extremely misleading: it's actually the closest ancestor that is returned.

The correct code would be:

```
var value = $(this).parent().siblings('td').children('input').val();
```

I wouldn't recommend binding the event handler to alllllllll anchor tags; this will be inefficient if there's a number of those elements on the page. Instead I would **strongly** recommend using [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead.

```
$('#objects').delegate('a.delete', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).parent('td').siblings('td').find('input').attr('value');
    alert(val);
});
```

This will bind the event handler to the `table` (once), and then uses JavaScripts event bubbling mechanisms to detect the click on the elements which match the selector passed in the first argument (in this case your delete buttons).

Comment: this second approach gives me ('#objects').delegate is not a function in firebug :/

Comment: @magda: You must be using an old version of jQuery. Delegate was added in 1.4.2. If you're using a version older than 1.3, but less than 1.4.2, you can use live instead: http://api.jquery.com/live. Or you can upgrade your version of jQuery to the latest (1.4.3)

Comment: yap you're right. I was using 1.4, so switched to google host. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [documentation for closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) you will see that it says that it finds ancestors ..

> **Description**: Get the first ***ancestor***
>   element that matches the selector,
>   beginning at the current element and
>   progressing ***up*** through the DOM tree.

the input in your case is not an ancestor of the `.delete` link.

You need to move up with `.closest('tr')` and then drill down to find the input with `.find('input')`

so

```
var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).parent("td").prev().find('input').val();
    alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### [See Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/opogi3/2)

---

You can't use `closest` there, try this:

```
 $('.delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).parent('td').prev('td').find('input').attr('value');
    alert(val);
 });
```

The `parent()` is used to go back to parent `td` of the link and then `prev()` is used to find the previous sibling of `td` and finally with `find` method, `input` is searched for.

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/parent/
- http://api.jquery.com/prev/
- http://api.jquery.com/find/