# Selecting nearest heading element

Tags: jquery

For a given element (which may be nested down in the DOM), I am trying to select it's 'closest' (nearest) heading element `<h1>`-`<h6>` in the DOM above. As the heading is not an ancestor, jQuery's `closest` will not suffice.

To clarify, the element is not likely to be a sibling of the headings - e.g. the `<span>`s of the code below.

Example HTML:

```
<section>
    <h1>Heading<h1>
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
          <p> ... <span class="where-am-i">What heading am I under?</span> ... </p>
      </li>
    </p>
    <!-- Should return the H2 above -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum... </p>
</section>
```

Similar, but different enough (I hope), to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068236/select-specific-closest-element) question.

Answer (score 1):

I have this solution, but it is long-winded. Is there anything easier that will clean up my code?

```
target = $(element)
    .parentsUntil("*:has('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')")  // element's ancestors until one which has children headings 
    .last()  // the ancestor that has sibling headings
    .prevUntil('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')   // previous siblings until the nearest heading
    .andSelf()  // in case the prevUntil() returns nothing
    .first()    // the first element after the heading
    .prev();    // the heading!
```

Here's my [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLzqkwFzAmuhKDGPW9la?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Did u try the following:

```
taget = $(element).closest(":header")
```

Comment: Thanks @Lini - I don't think `closest` works (on it's own) as it only traverses ancestors. The 'closest' heading will be a sibling of a parent.

Comment: Your Plnkr is not opening for me. Hence i gave a possible solution only.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.ancestorElement').closest().find().siblings('h1,h2,n3,h4,h5,h6');`

If provided HTML, a more accurate demo could be given?

Comment: Thanks zer0 - see plunker in my solution above.

Comment: @StevieP I refreshed a couple of times still don't see it, sir.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I didn't freeze it correctly. Try now. Or [this] (http://plnkr.co/edit/JLzqkwFzAmuhKDGPW9la?p=preview)