# Return a new jQuery collection from a jQuery plugin - use $.add?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Following a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340275/selecting-nearest-heading-element/35340276#35340276), I am writing a jQuery plugin (my first!) as a shortcut for finding any element's 'nearest' element that matches a selector (in my case any heading `<h1>` - `<h6>`) - 'nearest' meaning somewhere in the DOM above, further up the page.

Having read the [article in the jQuery learning centre](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), and a number of relevant StackOverflow posts, I've got this far:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.nearestAbove = function (selector) {
         var $new = $();
         this.each( function () {
             var $header = $(this).parentsUntil("*:has(" + selector + ")").prevUntil(selector).andSelf().first().prev();
             $new.add($header);
         });
         return $new;
     };
 }(jQuery));
```

I understand `.add()` can be used to add jQuery collections together - so I don't know why the plugin above is not working - it only returns an empty jQuery object.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLzqkwFzAmuhKDGPW9la?p=preview).

Help apprecitated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error.

```
$new = $new.add($header);
```